# How can I cycle through inventory file?

Tags: ansible

I would like to cycle inside my hosts inventory file in template module

ansible 2.8.1

file hosts
:

```
[servers]
test1 ansible_host=10.x.x.1 number=1
test2 ansible_host=10.x.x.2 number=2

- name: edit servers' file
    loop: "{{ groups['all'] }}"
    template:
      vars:
        peer: "{{ number }}"
      src: conf/ntp.j2
      dest: /etc/test.conf

I expected template j2 file with line:
{{ peer }}
replaced by number1 on test1
replaced by number2 on test2

fatal: [Server2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'number' is undefined"}
```

Comment: Hi Pierluigi, welcome to SO. There is no way that your actual file is indented like you have shown us, since (a) it is invalid YAML (b) even if it was valid, that would make a structure of `{"name":{"loop": "", "template": {"vars": {"peer": ""}}}}` which is for sure invalid ansible; please correct your indentation to be the same as your actual playbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below playbook. Use inventory_hostname/ansible_hostname.

```
- name: edit servers file
  template:
    vars:
      peer: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].number }}"
    src: conf/ntp.j2
    dest: /etc/test.conf
```